# How to insert delay between controllers in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

i want to add a delay between two controllers under my thread group containing different HTTP requests, so I tried applying the constant timer and think time. But the issue I am facing is that when I try to run my script with more than 1 thread the delay is not getting applied for a second time and it executes the requests immediately

for eg I have below script

Thread group

- Transaction controller 1
- HTTP request 1
- Delay
- Transaction controller 1
- HTTP request 2

When I set the user count as 2 and run it executes as below

HTTP request 1

HTTP request 1

waits for specified delay and then immediately executes the request 2

HTTP request 2

HTTP request 2

But I want it should execute like

HTTP request 1

HTTP request 1

delay

HTTP request 2

delay

HTTP request 2

what I need to do for this result?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zXEg.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to know 2 things:

1. Timers obey [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)
2. Timers create delay **before** each [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) in their scope

so if you want to create a delay between HTTP Request 1 and HTTP Request 2 you need to put the timer **as a child** of the HTTP Request 2

More information: [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer)

Comment: i tried as per your suggestion but still the result is the same for me

Answer (score 0):

Replace the Timer with a Flow Control Action PAUSE and you will have the behaviour that you want.

Comment: yes i tried this too but didnt work the HTTP request2 gets executed immediately